# Prove that $\Bbb P[\max_{k\le n}x_k<(2+)\sqrt{\log n}$ as $n\to \infty]=1$?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

> By the Borel-Cantelli lemma to prove that
>
> $\Bbb P[\max_{k\le n}x_k<(2+)\sqrt{\log n}$ as $n\to \infty]=1$ with a number $(2+)$ a shade more than 2.

The hint is to use $(1-x)^n>1-nx$.

Let $M_n=\max_{k\ge n}X_k$. Using independence

$$P\{M_n\ge x\}=\prod_{k\le n}P\{X_k\ge x\}=\left[1-\Phi(x)\right]^n$$

For $0<\epsilon<1$ and $m$ s.t. $(1-\epsilon)\sqrt{2\ln n}\ge 1$ for $n\ge m$ we have (using the lower bound for the tail of normal dist. $^{(*)}$)

$$
\sum_{n\ge m}P\{M_n>(1-\epsilon)2\sqrt{\ln n}\}\ge \sum_{n\ge m}\left[1-\frac{n^{-2(1-\epsilon)^2}}{2(1-\epsilon)\sqrt{2\pi\ln n}}\right]^n
$$
$$
\ge \sum_{n\ge m}1-n\frac{n^{-2(1-\epsilon)^2}}{2(1-\epsilon)\sqrt{2\pi\ln n}}
$$

which is not what I want, since I want this $\sum_{n\ge m}P\{M_n>(1-\epsilon)2\sqrt{\ln n}\}<\infty$, but using the hint, I get the opposite.

Am I using the hint in the wrong way?

Could someone kindly provide some help? Thanks very much!

Comment: $$\{M_n\ge x\}\ne\bigcap_{k\le n}P\{X_k\ge x\}$$

Comment: It would help to know the assumptions on the $X_k$ random variables. Distribution?  Independence?

Comment: In general I think you want $Pr[max < x] = Pr[all < x]$, which seems backwards from what you have.

Comment: $P(M_n \geq x)=1-P(M_n <x)=1-\prod_{k\leq n} P(X_k<x)$. The value you have in the first line after "Using independence" is actually $ P((\min_{k\leq n} X_k)\geq x).$